# Core/not-initialized in flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, dart-html, flutter-devtools

When I run my app I get the following error. I am 100% certain that I copy and pasted my "google-services.json" file in the correct directory.

[image]

***How can I solve this?***

Comment: Please share your code that you think is not working as intended and which might help us recreate the issue. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in the `index.html` file

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
```